# Overwritten .profile in OSX affecting Terminal Start

Tags: macos, .profile

The .profile on OSX 10.11.5  was overwritten by accident. When a path for PHP 7 is added to it, on Terminal launch we get:

```
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.RVAZ5aB2CN/Render"
declare -x HOME="/Users/fw"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="fw"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
declare -x PWD="/Users/fw"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.W5Sa8ZuiqH/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="361.1"
declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="2AA11A26-5380-4DE4-B1E2-550B9B9B5DE0"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/nm/hfxqj0d145l4pymv0nv6bs6m0000gn/T/"
declare -x USER="fw"
declare -x XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
declare -x XPC_SERVICE_NAME="0"
declare -x __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0x0:0x0"
```

The current content of .profile is:

```
export
PATH=/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/bin:$PATH
```

If the .profile is empty, none of the above appears in terminal on launch.

Any help would be appreciated.  (Also, if anyone knows if it is possible to restore a .profile, that would be great. ;-)  )

JD